# Find common lines between two files

Tags: linux, sorting, join, grep

File 1:

```
6
9219045
71608707
105853666
106000373
106000464
106000814
106001204
106001483
106002054
```

File 2:

```
6,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,jp-points
55555,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,jp-points
74292,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,jp-points
```

File 1 has only one column and I am sorting the file with the command `sort -n file1`

File 2 has three columns and I am sorting the file with command `sort -t "," -k 1n,1 file2` which is sorting on the basis of ist column.

Now, I want to find the rows in file2 that are starting from lines in file1

Commands that I have tried:

```
grep -w -f file1 file2

join -t "," -1 1 -2 1 -o 2.2 file1 file2
```

But, I am not getting desired results. Please provide me with alternate approach. File 1 has rows 7124458 and File 2 has row 42987432.

Comment: Try `split` - I am sure you can look that up

Answer (score 1):

Use awk:

```
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { ++a[$0]; next } $1 in a' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
6,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,jp-point
```

Answer (score 0):

join(1) assumes both files are sorted alphabetically on the join fields. Try sorting the inputs without -n.

(To be more precise, it depends on the LC_COLLATE setting. If you are sorting for the benefit of two programs talking to each other, it is probably more reliable to set LC_ALL=C for both join and sort to avoid any glitches due to locale settings.)